# Where the Datediff should go in a query which joins 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, join, datediff

I've completed the query below and it works, until I put Datediff into it.... then I get a syntax or some other sort of error. I'm pretty new to SQL.
I have tried putting the Datediff in between different lines, but it always errors. 
The Datediff is worded as follows:

```
Datediff(m, Table3.purchased,Table2.activity_date) AS Date_Difference
```

.

```
Select Table1.name, Table2.SK, Table3.key,Table3.purchased,Table3.count
from Table1
Inner Join Table2     On Table1.sk=Table2.sk
Inner Join Table3     On Table3.key=Table1.key
```

Apologies if this is really basic- but I am at a loss.
I've tried changing m (month) to mm and month, I've tried putting 'm', I've taken away the table references in the datediff (m,purchased,activity_date).
I've searched this site and moved the Datediff from the end of the sequence to the beginning, and then to after the first join... I'm sure I'm missing something simple.... but I can't figure it out. So any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql datediff use two param   you have 3

```
Datediff(Table3.purchased,Table2.activity_date) AS Date_Difference
```